# Growing NodeJS server: how to structure code?

Tags: node.js

So I have a NodeJS app, and it is starting to grow in size. Here a little background for the app:

1. It started as just an API to persist some things to a server.
2. The server started getting some more functionalities: more complex objects, object relationships, more complex requests.
3. The server started doing having socket programming capabilities.
4. The need for a custom admin dashboard came to be, so it was.
5. I started implementing a Web client on top of the API. The original client was an iPhone app but we saw the need for an additional client.

As of today, the way the app is built and organized is not terrible, mainly because all of the aforementioned additions were rather small. However I can see a maintenance nightmare announcing itself sooner than later if we don't modularize the application.

All the business logic lives in the routes: I have about a route per model, and everything that happens is defined there. I also have routes for searching. I have a single route for serving views, index.js, that I use for both the admin panel and the web client.

All of my mongo models live in the `/models` folder. They carry virtually no business logic.

Finally, the sockets and some routes do virtually the same thing, so there is a lot of copy pasted code right now. (Or at least they should be. Instead of copy pasting, I decided to make calls to my routes in my socket calls). Would it be a wiser idea to put common handlers in a separate file that can then be imported wherever needed?

How would I go about modularizing my server, keeping clients separated from server (ideally even in a different repository)? Any tips in general as to how to handle a growing server?

For information, my folder structure looks like this:

```
server
|
|-- bin
|-- models
|-- public
|-- routes
|-- views
|
|-- app.js
```

Answer (score 4):

The folder structure I used for my NodeJS API with Socket.io was:

```
server
|
|-- config
|-- controllers (Uses handler functions according to socket event)
|-- handlers (Uses mongo functions find, update etc.)
|-- models (Mongo models)
|-- public
|
|-- app.js (Uses controllers)
```

To wrap this up, a client wants to get his user details so he emits a user/get event via a socket. The server requires an user controller which handles this particular event. The controller function calls a get function from the user handler class. The controller retrieves a response from the handler function via a callback and emits the results (or error if something went wrong) to the client. Model View Controller(MVC) with socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator like express generator, gives you a structure for your client and server side, including a package.json file containing the templating engine you wish to use. Check it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator.